# "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'all'" when using "where" method from Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use Pandas' `where` method but I stuck with an error. Here is a very small example.

Give the file

```
Chamber,Treatment
1,Sem palha
1,Sem palha
1,Sem palha
2,Sem palha
2,Sem palha
```

when I run

```
import pandas
sample = pandas.read_csv('sample.csv')
sample.where(sample['Chamber'] == 1)
```

I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-96ed02cb41da> in <module>()
----> 1 sample.where(sample['Chamber'] == 1)

/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in where(self, cond, other, inplace, axis, level, try_cast, raise_on_error)
   3346             new_data = self._data.where(other=other, cond=cond, align=axis is None,
   3347                                         raise_on_error=raise_on_error,
-> 3348                                         try_cast=try_cast)
   3349 
   3350             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)

/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in where(self, **kwargs)
   2434 
   2435     def where(self, **kwargs):
-> 2436         return self.apply('where', **kwargs)
   2437 
   2438     def eval(self, **kwargs):

/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, **kwargs)
   2416                                                  copy=align_copy)
   2417 
-> 2418             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
   2419 
   2420             if isinstance(applied, list):

/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in where(self, other, cond, align, raise_on_error, try_cast)
   1043         axis = cond.ndim - 1
   1044         cond = cond.swapaxes(axis, 0)
-> 1045         mask = np.array([cond[i].all() for i in range(cond.shape[0])],
   1046                         dtype=bool)
   1047 

/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1043         axis = cond.ndim - 1
   1044         cond = cond.swapaxes(axis, 0)
-> 1045         mask = np.array([cond[i].all() for i in range(cond.shape[0])],
   1046                         dtype=bool)
   1047 

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Comment: `sample.where` expects a boolean array or NDFrame of the same shape as `sample`. What is the desired result? Did you want `sample['Chamber'].where(sample['Chamber'] == 1)` for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As unutbu pointed out in the comment, `where` seems to be a "cell-wise" selection. These to variants work as expected:

```
sample[sample["Chamber"] == 1]
```

and

```
sample.query("Chamber == 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax would actually work in new versions of pandas. You can upgrade pandas on Ubuntu using

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Or if you are using python3, then

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```