# Replace zeros in one dataframe with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes df1 and df2:
df1 is shown here:

```
   age
0   42
1   52
2   36
3   24
4   73
```

df2 is shown here:

```
   age
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0
```

I want to replace all the zeros in df2 with their corresponding entries in df1. In more technical words, if the element at a certain index in df2 is zero, then I would want this element to be replaced by the corresponding entry in df1.

Hence, I want df2 to look like:

```
   age
0    42
1    52
2    1
3    24
4    73
```

I tried using the replace method but it is not working. Please help :)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
In [19]: df2.where(df2 != 0, df1)
Out[19]: 
   age
0   42
1   52
2    1
3   24
4   73
```

Above, `df2 != 0` is a boolean DataFrame.

```
In [16]: df2 != 0
Out[16]: 
     age
0  False
1  False
2   True
3  False
4  False
```

`df2.where(df2 != 0, df1)` returns a new DataFrame. Where `df2 != 0` is True, the corresponding value of `df2` is used. Where it is False, the corresponding value of `df1` is used.

---

Another alternative is to make an assignment with [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df2.loc[df2['age'] == 0, 'age'] = df1['age']
```

`df.loc[mask, col]` selects rows of `df` where the boolean Series, `mask` is True, and where the column label is `col`.

```
In [17]: df2.loc[df2['age'] == 0, 'age']
Out[17]: 
0    0
1    0
3    0
4    0
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

When used in an assignment, such as `df2.loc[df2['age'] == 0, 'age'] = df1['age']`,
Pandas performs automatic index label alignment. (Notice the index labels above are 0,1,3,4 -- with 2 being skipped). So the values in `df2.loc[df2['age'] == 0, 'age']` are replaced by the corresponding values from `d1['age']`. Even though `d1['age']` is a Series with index labels `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`, and `4`, the `2` is ignored because there is no corresponding index label on the left-hand side.

In other words,

```
df2.loc[df2['age'] == 0, 'age'] = df1.loc[df2['age'] == 0, 'age']
```

would work as well, but the added restriction on the right-hand side is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you. However, when I try df2.where(df2['age'] != 0, df1) I get AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: I think you are experiencing [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26973803/190597) -- you can fix it by upgrading your version of pandas.

Comment: The pandas version cannot be changed because its installed on a server and I can only use that one :( The pandas version I have is 0.15.1'

Comment: Then I believe you could use `df2.loc[df2['age'] == 0, 'age'] = df1['age']` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot works great ! :) Could you be kind enough to explain how this code works as well ?  and even how the df2.where(df2 != 0, df1) works

Answer (score 3):

```
In [30]: df2.mask(df2==0).combine_first(df1)
Out[30]:
    age
0  42.0
1  52.0
2   1.0
3  24.0
4  73.0
```

or "negating" [beautiful @unutbu's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45701659/5741205):

```
In [46]: df2.mask(df2==0, df1)
Out[46]:
   age
0   42
1   52
2    1
3   24
4   73
```

Comment: @Vaishali, yes, thank you! It's a "negation" of beautiful unutbu's solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Or try `mul`

```
df1.mul(np.where(df2==1,0,1)).replace({0:1})
```