# How to replace values in a dataframes with values in another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframes

```
df_1: 

Week   Day    Coeff_1      ...  Coeff_n

1      1             12           23
1      2             11           19   
1      3             23           68
1      4             57           81
1      5             35           16
1      6             0            0
1      7             0            0

...

50      1             12           23
50      2             11           19   
50      3             23           68
50      4             57           81
50      5             35           16
50      6             0            0
50      7             0            0
```

```
df_2: 

Week   Day    Coeff_1      ...  Coeff_n

1      1             0           0
1      2             0           0   
1      3             0           0
1      4             0           0
1      5             0           0
1      6             56          24
1      7             20          10

...

50      1             0           0
50      2             0           0   
50      3             0           0
50      4             0           0
50      5             0           0
50      6             10          84
50      7             29          10
```

In the first dataframe `df_1` I have coefficients for monday to friday. In the second dataframes `df_2` I have coefficients for the week end. My goal is to merge both dataframes such that I have no longer 0 values which are obsolete.

What is the best approach to do that?
I found that using `df.replace` seems to be a good approach

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace zeros in one dataframe with values from another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701538/replace-zeros-in-one-dataframe-with-values-from-another-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your dataframes follow the same structure, you can capitalise on `pandas` functionality to [`align automatically on indexes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html#intro-to-data-structures). Thus you can `replace` `0`'s with `np.nan` in df1, and then use `fillna`:

```
df1.replace({0:np.nan},inplace=True)
df1.fillna(df2)

    Week  Day  Coeff_1  Coeff_n
0    1.0  1.0     12.0     23.0
1    1.0  2.0     11.0     19.0
2    1.0  3.0     23.0     68.0
3    1.0  4.0     57.0     81.0
4    1.0  5.0     35.0     16.0
5    1.0  6.0     56.0     24.0
6    1.0  7.0     20.0     10.0
7   50.0  1.0     12.0     23.0
8   50.0  2.0     11.0     19.0
9   50.0  3.0     23.0     68.0
10  50.0  4.0     57.0     81.0
11  50.0  5.0     35.0     16.0
12  50.0  6.0     10.0     84.0
13  50.0  7.0     29.0     10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just append the rows df_1 where day is 1-5 to the rows of df_2 where day is 6-7?

`df_3 = df_1[df_1.Day.isin(range(1,6))].append(df_2[df_2.Day.isin(range(6,8))])`

To get a normal sorting, you can sort your values by week and day:

`df_3.sort_values(['Week','Day'])`